# Passing values to required fields that do not come from inputs in Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a ModelForm. There are several fields such as:

```
['display_from', 'display_to', 'position', 'image']
```

However, display_from and display_to are not in my template. I want to override the validation and assign those fields some values before any validation errors appear. I have done something like this:

```
def clean(self):
    position = self.cleaned_data.get('position')
    image = self.cleaned_data.get('image')

    display_from = "value here"
    display_to = "value here"

    self.cleaned_data['display_from'] = display_from
    self.cleaned_data['display_to'] = display_to

    return self.cleaned_data
```

When I print the cleaned_data, I can see the values in the terminal. However, when I display the error messages on the page, it tells me that display_from and display_to are required.

Perhaps this should not be done in the clean() method?

I tried to use empty hidden inputs as well, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Excluding the fields does not help, it returns an IntegrityError message:

```
null value in column "display_from" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: Have you excluded the fields in the meta ?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind the clean() function is called *after* the various clean_ functions for each field on the model (docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation)).

So those individual field clean functions will be raising ValidationErrors that get pinned to the form.errors dict before your clean() function comes in and adds the default values to the cleaned_data dict.

You could also carry on with the approach you already started with. Just remove the errors from the errors dict.

```
def clean(self):
   del form.errors['display_from']
   del form.errors['display_to']
   display_from = "value here"
   display_to = "value here"

   self.cleaned_data['display_from'] = display_from
   self.cleaned_data['display_to'] = display_to

   return self.cleaned_data
```

There are a few other approaches.

For very simple cases you can get away with using a hidden field in your form.

You can also override the clean_ method to return the appropriate value. These generated values may be passed to the ModelForm constructor:

```
form = SomeModelForm(request.POST or None, initial={"option": "10"})
```

Answer (score -1):

You would need to add those fields to your `exclude` tuple:

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ('display_from', 'display_to',)
        model = YourModel

    def clean(self):
        . . .
```

Then you won't get the required field error and can override the validation as you wish.

Comment: It gives me an error message, I have tried it already: `null value in column "display_from" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: maybe because the excluded fields do not get saved in the model instance? In `clean` try setting them like this: `self.instance.display_from = "value here"` (and of course, `self.cleaned_data['display_from'] = self.instance.display_from` )

Comment: I've found this is often unworkable due to Model fields being blank=False.

Comment: Well, of course you have to set the field values if you're overriding the validation and excluding them. There's no harm in setting the fields to `blank=True` if you're doing some custom override and taking responsibility for the value yourself. I'm not sure how else you do what the O.P. asked without excluding the values.